# what does a semicolon before a function mean?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at an open source project, and see something like this :

```
;(function(){
    // codes here
})()
```

I'd like to know whether the semicolon there has a special meaning?

Comment: That's a semicolon.  It's probably there in case the file is imported after another file that's missing a trailing semicolon.

Comment: @Pointy thanks. could you post it in an answer so I can accept it to end this question.

Answer (score 7):

This is because the ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) allows you to avoid semicolons.

For example, you can write this kind of code with no error:

```
var a = 1
a.fn = function() {
    console.log(a)
}
```

See? Not a single semicolon.

However, there are cases where the semicolon isn't inserted. Basically, in real projects, there is one case where it isn't: when the next line starts with a parenthesis.

The javascript parser will take the next line as an argument and not automatically add a semicolon.

Example:

```
var a = 1
(function() {})()
// The javascript parser will interpret this as "var a = 1(function() {})()", leading to a syntax error
```

To avoid this, there are several ways:

- Add a semicolon at the beginning of a line starting with a parenthesis (which was done in the code you show)
- Use the following structure:

  `!function() {}()`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion (see section 7.9 in [ECMAScript Language 
Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)):

> There are three basic rules of semicolon insertion:
>
> 1. When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token (called the offending token) is encountered that 
>      is not allowed by any production of the grammar, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the 
>      offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true:
>
>    - The offending token is separated from the previous token by at least one *LineTerminator*.
>    - The offending token is `}`.
> 2. When, as the program is parsed from left to right, the end of the input stream of tokens is encountered and the parser is unable to parse the input token stream as a single complete ECMAScript Program, then a semicolon is automatically inserted at the end of the input stream.

Usually you can omit the last semicolon in a JavaScript file (second rule). If your application creates JavaScript code by merging several files this will result in a syntax error. Since `;` itself is the empty statement you can use it to prevent such syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

A very good explanation can be found here:

https://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/
(see paragraph "The only real pitfall when coding without semicolons")

```
var x = y
(a == b).print()
```

is evaluated as

```
var x = y(a == b).print()
```

Bottom line, it's a good practice to put a semicolon before every row that starts with a "(" character